# PHP check if current time is between two times

Tags: php, time

I have a start and end time in milliseconds.

I have to get all the TV series that are ON AIR when the user visits the page.

So I am trying to do this:

```
if($prog["inizio"] < time() && $prog["fine"] > time()){
        array_push($programmazioneFinal[$date."-".$prog["id_canale"]], $prog);
}
```

The logic is to get only those series whose starting time is lower than now (the serie is already started) and the end time is bigger than now.

For some reasons it is also returning those series that start much later in the day, not just the ones ON AIR now.

What's wrong?

I have added a screenshot of my DB just to make this clearer.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to do it on php side, instead of DB side ?

Comment: If you are doing it on php side, take my answer... else take @Julio's answer

Comment: Likely your *inizio* is wrong and probably 0 (`*null* < time()` is true) . Thus you get even the ones not started. Check the PHP code that reads the DB.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP: You can use [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). This will give you timestamp value which you can use for comparison

```
strtotime("now")
```

Edit in your code

```
if($prog["inizio"] < strtotime("now") && $prog["fine"] > strtotime("now")){
        array_push($programmazioneFinal[$date."-".$prog["id_canale"]], $prog);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your query look like

```
Select * from ... WHERE UNIX_TIME($your_date_parameter) BETWEEN inizio AND fine
```